# How to change the buffer limit in Google's protobuf?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I'm getting this warning and an error afterwards when I try to parse a large message. I know than 64MB which is the default limit. I am using message.ParseFromIstream now. Does any one know to get access to CodedInputStream object to call the SetTotalBytesLimit function? or any other way to solve this problem?

> Reading dangerously large protocol message. If the message turns out
>   to be larger than 67108864 bytes, parsing will be halted for security
>   reasons. To increase the limit (or to disable these warnings), see
>   CodedInputStream::SetTotalBytesLimit() in
>   google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.h.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The correct fix: You should try to limit the sizes of your protobuf messages. Please see:
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques#streaming

The quick and dirty (read not recommended) approach:
In the file coded_stream.h of the protobuf library source, change the values of `kDefaultTotalBytesLimit` and `kDefaultTotalBytesWarningThreshold`, recompile, and reinstall.

Comment: Instead of proposing to manage your own branch of the protobuf code (ugh), one can just manually construct the CodedInputStream and use that one. Redesigning the application would most likely be the best option, but there's really absolutely no reason to maintain your own branch.

Comment: It looks like the latest protobuf does not enforce this limit anymore. You can just move to latest protobuf as well. https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.h#L639

Answer (score 9):

Just reading the documentation of the function that the error already told you about, would've answered that question:

> Hint: If you are reading this because your program is printing a
>   warning about dangerously large protocol messages, you may be confused
>   about what to do next. The best option is to change your design such
>   that excessively large messages are not necessary. For example, try to
>   design file formats to consist of many small messages rather than a
>   single large one. If this is infeasible, you will need to increase the
>   limit. Chances are, though, that your code never constructs a
>   CodedInputStream on which the limit can be set. You probably parse
>   messages by calling things like Message::ParseFromString(). In this
>   case, you will need to change your code to instead construct some sort
>   of ZeroCopyInputStream (e.g. an ArrayInputStream), construct a
>   CodedInputStream around that, then call
>   Message::ParseFromCodedStream() instead. Then you can adjust the
>   limit. Yes, it's more work, but you're doing something unusual.

[Source](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.io.coded_stream#CodedInputStream.SetTotalBytesLimit.details)

Also it's probably a really good idea to follow the first part of the advice and redesign the application.

Comment: My current design is like this. I have an Image message which has a lot of things. In addition to that I have ImageSet which has a repeated Image in it. Each ImageSet is written to a file and I have several ImageSets because of file sizes. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Not exactly clear what you're doing, but personally I'd make it so that the ImageSet only contains references to the actual images, which would make for quite a small message. Obviously one message per image which also shouldn't be anywhere close to the 65MB limit either. You can still store all of it in one file without much extra work. Although I'm not sure why you're using protobuf and not a DB if all you do is store it in the local FS.

Comment: My program is a scientific application where I'm analyzing images and saving results in files, etc. That's why an Image message becomes very large.

Comment: So you have single images that are larger than 64MB? Surprising, but certainly possible. Yep in that case you'll have to increase the message size - although I still don't see why you'd want to use the FS and protobuf here and not just a DB. That's exactly what they're there for.

Comment: The thing is that an Image with all the extra annotations and data will be smaller than 64MB. But ImageSets will be more.

Comment: That's why you shouldn't store the complete image data in ImageSets, but only references (filenames, guids, whatever) to the actual images, that makes the ImageSets trivially small without much overhead (and enables some advantages like reusing the same image in several sets)

Answer (score 4):

[Here's a comment from the code](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/8f67b165f0a949219fafc48c533be3fbf53497b7/src/google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.h#L340) (`google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.h`) that sets the message limit for those who's wondering what is the security reason they are talking about. In my case I cannot modify how my application work so I have to change this limit.

This thread is quite old, but recently deep learning has got attention and the library Caffe used Protobuf so maybe more people will stumbled upon this. I have to do neural network stuff with Caffe, and the whole network took so much memory even with smallest batch size.

```
  // Total Bytes Limit -----------------------------------------------
  // To prevent malicious users from sending excessively large messages
  // and causing integer overflows or memory exhaustion, CodedInputStream
  // imposes a hard limit on the total number of bytes it will read.

  // Sets the maximum number of bytes that this CodedInputStream will read
  // before refusing to continue.  To prevent integer overflows in the
  // protocol buffers implementation, as well as to prevent servers from
  // allocating enormous amounts of memory to hold parsed messages, the
  // maximum message length should be limited to the shortest length that
  // will not harm usability.  The theoretical shortest message that could
  // cause integer overflows is 512MB.  The default limit is 64MB.  Apps
  // should set shorter limits if possible.  If warning_threshold is not -1,
  // a warning will be printed to stderr after warning_threshold bytes are
  // read.  For backwards compatibility all negative values get squashed to -1,
  // as other negative values might have special internal meanings.
  // An error will always be printed to stderr if the limit is reached.
  //
  // This is unrelated to PushLimit()/PopLimit().
  //
  // Hint:  If you are reading this because your program is printing a
  //   warning about dangerously large protocol messages, you may be
  //   confused about what to do next.  The best option is to change your
  //   design such that excessively large messages are not necessary.
  //   For example, try to design file formats to consist of many small
  //   messages rather than a single large one.  If this is infeasible,
  //   you will need to increase the limit.  Chances are, though, that
  //   your code never constructs a CodedInputStream on which the limit
  //   can be set.  You probably parse messages by calling things like
  //   Message::ParseFromString().  In this case, you will need to change
  //   your code to instead construct some sort of ZeroCopyInputStream
  //   (e.g. an ArrayInputStream), construct a CodedInputStream around
  //   that, then call Message::ParseFromCodedStream() instead.  Then
  //   you can adjust the limit.  Yes, it's more work, but you're doing
  //   something unusual.
```