# Protobuf design

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have a message Image which has a lot of things in it and a message ImageSet which stores multiple images.

```
message Image {
    ...
}
message ImageSet {
    repeated Image images = 1;
}
```

I also multiple ImageSets because I do not want to save everything in one file. The problem that I have is that each ImageSet becomes very large and I get warnings/errors because of that. Is there a better way of designing this?

Note that I parse file like this.

```
ImageSet image_set;
image_set.ParseFromIstream(stream);
```

Comment: I asked another question about the warnings here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13849434/how-to-change-the-buffer-limit-in-googles-protobuf

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use protobuf-messages to send your image data objects. You can design something like this to describe images:

```
message Image {
    required int64 bytes_size = 1;
}

message ImageSet {
    repeated Image images = 1;
}
```

To specify count and size of each image data you send. Than just send images date after your message through socket and read on another side in the same order.

On the sender's side:

```
socket.write(protobuf_message_size); // for example 8 bytes    
socket.write(protobuf_message);
socket.write(binary_images_data);
```

Comment: I'm storing my ImageSets in files. Are you suggesting to write multiple Images into a file without using ImageSet?

Comment: Not really. I thought that you store your images in proto-classes as binary field.

Comment: I'm not storing images but some statistical information from images that can be large. That's why the image messages become large in size.

Comment: Some sort of gradient histogram and different orientation... like dense sift http://www.vlfeat.org/api/dsift.html

Anyways, the result is I'd have data in the order of few megabytes per image stored in my Image message.

Comment: I got it now. As i said, you dont have to send your image in protobuf-messages, you can specify only size of size of each imege and send you image data after protobuf-message.